# Altium room moving objects from another layer

Tags: altium

I have found a few other questions with the exact same problem but without answer, and i need to make sense of it because i cannot fathom how stupid it is for a supossedly professional program as Altium.
I have two rooms, one in the top layer and another one in the bottom layer. As most rooms do, they have tracks, vias, and pours, which is expected.

[image]

Now, if I move the top room over the bottom room, everything its ok:
[image]

But why, for the love of god, if I move again the top room it moves with itself all of the tracks and vias and polygon pours that were on the bottom room? Now, vias I can understand as they are multilayer objects, but tracks on another completely different layer????
[image]

Sorry if I sound too snarky. I'm tired of this problem and haven't found a way to work around it.

Comment: Does it do that in single-layer mode (Shift-S)?

Comment: Yes, it does that even if the layer is not visible or it is on single layer mode.

Comment: Welcome to Altium.  It's great when it's great and very annoying other times.  Note the issue you state varies with Altium release but has never been truly fixed. Why can't you just use one room to both top and bottom?

Comment: Why can't you just use one room to both top and bottom?